# cake php can't login "wrong username and password"

Tags: cakephp

help, i can't login with my username and password i was see the script controller model and view but i not understand the error
it's my AppController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Application level Controller
 *
 * This file is application-wide controller file. You can put all
 * application-wide controller-related methods here.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller 
{
    public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar','Session','Auth','Acl' => array
                                (
                                    'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'))
                                )
                                );
    public function isAuthorized($user) 
        {
            // Admin can access every action
            if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            // Default deny
            return false;
        }
    public function beforeFilter() 
        {
            //$this->Auth->allow();
            //Configure AuthComponent
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array
                (
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                );
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array
                (
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action' => 'login'
                );
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array
                (
                    'controller' => 'posts',
                    'action' => 'add'
                );
        }
    public $helpers = array('Session','Html','Form');

}

?>
```

this my user.php

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 * @property Post $Post
 */
class User extends AppModel {
    public function bindNode($user) 
        {
            return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
        }
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));
    public function parentNode() 
        {
            if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
            if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) 
                {
                    $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
                } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
                }
            if (!$groupId) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) 
        {
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
            $this->data['User']['password']
            );
            return true;
        }


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

and this my login.ctp

```
    <?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array('legend' => __('Login'),'username','password'));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

please help me.
my fields just username, password
But the username and password wrong again ..

Comment: Your app controller code is not relevant - neither is most of the user model code. Please clean up your question and tag with the version of CakePHP you are using (and format the code in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an obvious error:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) 
{
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    return true;
}
```

What that will do is set the user's password to the hash of a blank string whenever the user record is saved and the password is not in the model's data, "changing" the password.

### Solution

Follow [the documentation for the version of CakePHP you are using](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) for example:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            return true;
        }
    
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Be sure to follow the documentation for the version of CakePHP you are using as the Auth component's behavior changed significantly over time.

Answer (score 0):

Add This in UsersTable.php

public function beforeSave(Event $event)
            {
                $entity = $event->data['entity'];

```
            // Make a password for digest auth.
            $entity->digest_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
                $entity->username,
                $entity->password,
                env('SERVER_NAME')
            );
            return true;
        }
```